How can I read the Voltage supplied from PMBUS or SMBus
I am able to control the voltage supplied to a desktop. How can I read that voltage back using Linux terminal. I have tried i2c and hwmon and nothing seemed to have the right values.

I feel like there's a few missing parts of the question - is the desktop using an ATX PSU or something else? How are you controlling the voltage and where?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
